# How to select inverse of query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have Three tables one for Users, One for User Services, And One for services

> the Users table is (id, username, email, password)

And

> The Services Table is (id, Servicename, Servicesdetails, price)

And

> The userservices Table is (id, userid, serviceid, startdate, enddate)

When user Log in to his dashboard he can see all services he had.
And Services he don't have.
For all services he had I used this query and worked perfectly.

```
$mysql_servicesadded = "SELECT * FROM services INNER JOIN userservices ON userservices.serviceid = services.id WHERE userservices.userid = '".$user."' ORDER BY userservices.startdate DESC";
$query_servicesadded = $dblink->query($m$mysql_servicesadded) or die ("Cannot Get Services");
```

And then Fetch it and echo it
But to get all services user doesn't have I don't know what query to use.
Please Any Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    services
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(
SELECT
    userservices.serviceid
FROM
    userservices
WHERE
    userservices.serviceid = services.id 
AND
    userservices.userid = '".$user."'
)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

I think, as we are selecting the services, not attached to this user, there is no need to ORDER BY userservices.startdate.

Answer (score 4):

Use outer join, it will select you all the services

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
LEFT OUTER JOIN userservices ON userservices.serviceid = services.id 
WHERE userservices.userid = '".$user."' 
ORDER BY userservices.startdate DESC";
```

If you have data from columns from `userservices` table, it is connected to the user. If you don't, it's not connected.

Then from PHP you can iterate through and check them.

Comment: @user1974729 That is a good trick, you can do it with 1 `select`. It is always good to save some resources :)

Comment: The `OUTER` keyword is optional, just to clarify that this is the functionality of the common LEFT JOIN. Clearly the best option since you want to list all services anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this (Notice the NOT IN).

```
SELECT * FROM services WHERE serviceid NOT IN 
(SELECT serviceid FROM userservices WHERE userid='".$user."') 
ORDER BY serviceid DESC
```

You can also use (NOT) EXISTS.